# How do they describe in Russian the act of a soldier clicking his heels together?

Tags: выбор-слова

How do they describe in Russian the act of a soldier clicking his heels together, which was very common in the pre-revolutionary Russian army?

For example, how to say in Russian "I saw him click his heels together when the general approached him"?

Comment: Notice that this action is rather connected to a sort-of showing off or officers in tsar army, this is in a sense an outdated gesture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's *щёлкать/щёлкнуть каблуками*.

> Я увидел, как он щёлкнул каблуками, когда генерал приблизился (к нему).